# Replace multiple pixels value in an image with a certain value Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image 640x480 `img`, and I want to replace pixels having values not in this list or array `x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with a certain value `10`, so that any pixel in `img` which doesn't have the any of the values in `x` will be replaced with `10`. I already know how to replace only one value using `img(img~=1)=10` or multiple values using this `img(img~=1 & img~=2 & img~=3 & img~=4 & img~=5)=10` but I when I tried this `img(img~=x)=10` it gave an error saying `Matrix dimensions must agree`. So if anyone could please advise.

Comment: Very interesting problem!  One that I've had to figure out and solve many a time.  Thanks for asking the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this very easily with a combination of [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).  We can create a 3D column vector that consists of the elements of `[1,2,3,4,5]`, then use `bsxfun` with the not equals method (`@ne`) on your image (assuming grayscale) so that we thus create a 3D matrix of 5 slices.  Each slice would tell you whether the locations in the image **do not** match an element in `x`.  The first slice would give you the locations that **don't** match `x = 1`, the second slice would give you the locations that **don't** match `x = 2`, and so on.

Once you finish this, we can use an [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) call operating on the third dimension to consolidate the pixel locations that are not equal to all of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.  The last step would be to take this `logical` map, which that tells you the locations that are none of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 and we'd set those locations to 10.

One thing we need to consider is that the image type and the vector `x` must be the same type.  We can ensure this by casting the vector to be the same class as `img`.

As such, do something like this:

```
x = permute([1 2 3 4 5], [3 1 2]);
vals = bsxfun(@ne, img, cast(x, class(img)));
ind = all(vals, 3);
img(ind) = 10;
```

The advantage of the above method is that the list you want to use to check for the elements can be whatever you want.  It prevents having messy logical indexing syntax, like `img(img ~= 1 & img ~= 2 & ....)`.  All you have to do is change the input list at the beginning line of the code, and `bsxfun`, `permute` and `any` should do the work for you.

Here's an example 5 x 5 image:

```
>> rng(123123);
>> img = randi(7, 5, 5)

img =

     3     4     3     6     5
     7     2     6     5     1
     3     1     6     1     7
     6     4     4     3     3
     6     2     4     1     3
```

By using the code above, the output we get is:

```
img =

     3     4     3    10     5
    10     2    10     5     1
     3     1    10     1    10
    10     4     4     3     3
    10     2     4     1     3
```

You can most certainly see that those elements that are neither 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 get set to 10.

## Aside

If you don't like the `permute` and `bsxfun` approach, one way would be to have a `for` loop and with an initially all `true` array, keep logical ANDing the final result with a `logical` map that consists of those locations which are not equal to each value in `x`.  In the end, we will have a logical map where `true` are those locations that are neither equal to 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Therefore, do something like this:

```
ind = true(size(img));
for idx = 1 : 5
    ind = ind & img ~= idx;
end
img(ind) = 10;
```

If you do this instead, you'll see that we get the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach #1**

You can use [`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), 
which according to its official documentation for a case of `ismember(A,B)` would output a logical array of the same size as `A` and with `1`'s where
any element from `B` is present in `A`, `0`'s otherwise. Since, you are looking to detect `"not in the list or array"`, you need to invert it afterwards, i.e. `~ismember()`.

In your case, you have `img` as `A` and `x` as `B`, so `~ismember(img,x)` would give you those places where `img~=any element in x`
You can then map into `img` to set all those in it to `10` with this final solution -

```
img(~ismember(img,x)) = 10
```

---

**Approach #2**

Similar to [`rayryeng's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29089898/3293881), you can use [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), but keep it in `2D` which could be more efficient as it would also avoid `permute`. The implementation would look something like this -

```
img(reshape(all(bsxfun(@ne,img(:),x(:).'),2),size(img))) = 10
```

Comment: @shepherd: IMHO, the `ismember` approach is the way to go both for memory and readability considerations.

Comment: @Jonas Agreed on both accounts!